# pushViewController at didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
     if (tvc == nil)
     tvc = [[TopicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopicViewController" bundle:nil];
     tvc.title = @"Topic";
     tvc.topicId = [[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
     [tvc release];

}
```

So when I tap on the row it is able to bring this table view. Then I press navigate back and choose a different row, then the app crashes. I tried to see in the console for any error, but can't find any. What is wrong?

Comment: this code looks fine. you can use breakpoints to find out which part is giving problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your (tvc == nil) is returning NO because you released tvc but didn't set it to nil so next time this method is accessed, you try and push it as a view controller without allocating it again, hence the crash.

You can either remove the `if (tvc == nil)` check or release tvc and then set it to nil with `[tvc release], tvc = nil;`.

The other possibility is your `results` array is being released. Where is it initialised and have you declared a retain property for it? If so you can access it with `[self.results objectAtIndex:...]` which will guarantee it will stick around until your view controller is deallocated.

Comment: its fine if you dont give brackets. it means that only the next line in the code is considered as the part of if statement. like this `if(){something;}` is valid and `if()something;` is also valid

Comment: @robin you're right but my point is still valid about checking for nil. Just because the object has been released it doesn't mean it is nil. I'll edit my response accordingly.

Comment: thats not true if you try to access any object that is released it will give you EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the console.

Comment: removing if (tvc == nil) works... so if I want to remove the if(tvc == nil) then is there anything else that I need to do to prevent memory leaks

Comment: Your code is fine without `(tvc==nil)`. You `[[alloc]init]` the view controller, push it into the view and then `[release]` ownership of it. No memory leaks in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tvc` is a declared property that retains an object, do

```
self.tvc = [[TopicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopicViewController" bundle:nil];
//....
self.tvc = nil;
[tvc release];
```

instead of

```
tvc = [[TopicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopicViewController" bundle:nil];
//....
[tvc release];
```

However, I wouldn't release the view controller and re-allocate it at all, because a memory allocation is expensive. I would just store one tvc object and reuse it, by modifying it according to the selected row.

Comment: The suggestion to use `self.tvc = ...` instead of `tvc = ...` is wrong since that would produce a memory leak when `tvc` is declared as a retain object. The object is first retained by alloc/init and then again by the property. When set to nil it is only released once and you have a memory leak.

Comment: You are right. I meant self.tvc=nil AND [tvc release] but my description clearly was wrong. Thank you for your correction. I edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@Equinox i think you need to do something like this

```
 tvc.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Topic"];
 tvc.topicId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

Edit: i think you are over releasing some objects in your `TopicViewController` class so your app is getting crash with out any message in the console. what you can do is build and analyze your project to check for any over releasing objects

Comment: This will only produce a memory leak if title and topicId are declared as a copy property, which they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You're always releasing, even if it's not allocated.